# Proof of $|a-b| < b \implies a > 0$

Tags: inequality, proof-writing, absolute-value

$|a-b|< b \implies a > 0 $

This seems obvious and like common sense, but how can I prove this in a formally correct way?

Comment: Note that $|x|\geqslant x$ for all $x.$

Comment: $|x| < c$ iff $-c<x<c$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$|a-b|<b \iff -b<a-b<b \iff 0<a<2b.$$

Answer (score 1):

Prove by contradiction. The first thing to notice is that $b\geq0$, because absolute values never go below zero. Assume, therefore, that $a<0$, then $a-b$ is going to be negative, so the value of the absolute value is $b-a$. Since $a<0$ in our assumption, then $b-a-b=-a>0$. This leads to a contradiction. Therefore, $a\geq0$. Finally, prove $a\neq0$.

Answer (score 1):

$$|a-b|<b\implies a-b<b \text{ and } -(a-b)<b \text{ and } b>0$$
$$a-b<b \text{ and } b>0 \implies 0<a<2b$$
$$-(a-b)<b \implies b-a<b \implies -a<0 \implies 0<a$$

So by either case, $0<a$.